# Jenkins is unable to recognise the Parent Pom file

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

When I'm running the CI Job locally everything is working as expected. When I'm executing the same via Jenkins, few times it is able to recognize the POM file and few times it is unable to recognize the POM file. And throws the error stating " Non readable POM".

Checked on the docker agent where this job is running and found that Jenkins is only recognizing the file folders but not the POM file (available on the root).

The ls command result proved me that Jenkins is not picking the POM file.

Comment: Please show the error log ... ?

Comment: [FATAL] Non-readable POM /jenkins/workspace/CI-Pipeline/CIJob/./pom.xml: /jenkins/workspace/CI-Pipeline/CIJob/./pom.xml (No such file or directory) @ 
 @

Comment: Can you show your pom file of  the project which does not work?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I hope you are safe and your family too. I cannot show the pom file due to confidentiality. But I can tell you that this is a simple pom file with very minimal data

Comment: But the error message shows the project is not located there ...either SCM in Jenkins is wrongly configured or the job itself is wrongly configured ...I can't tell...

Comment: Thanks, I have figured it out. This issue is caused because SCM was set to default checkout true, and hence Jenkins is unable to read my latest changes. I changed it to false and it did the magic.